# How to sync Windows Mobile 6.1 phone with Kontact, Evolution, or Sunbird

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, windows-mobile, evolution

I would like to synchronize my Windows mobile 6.1 phone with Kontact. I'm somewhat flexible and would be willing to use Evolution or Sun bird.

Provide step-by-step instruction in Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope

Answer (score 1):

From [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6258719&postcount=6/)

First you need to add better repositories. You can get it to work with the standard packages in Ibex, but it doesn't work as smoothly.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add this to the bottom of the file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/synce/ubuntu intrepid main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/synce/ubuntu intrepid main
```

The necessary modules are already included in the Intrepid kernel. Install the core libraries:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synce-hal librra0-tools librapi2-tools
```

Now connect your device to the computer and run:

```
synce-pls
```

You should see a list of files on your device. If you device is password protected, then you will get this error:

```
. WARNING **: synce_info_from_odccm: Failed to get a connection for <device_name>: Not authenticated, you need to call !ProvidePassword with the correct password. pls: Could not find configuration at path '(Default)'
You will need to install synce-trayicon or synce-kpm.
```

If you have the Gnome Network Manager running on Ubuntu, it will setup your device as the new default network connection. Check what ethernet device was given to your device with by running the following command in a terminal after you have connected your device:

```
/sbin/ifconfig -a | grep 80:00:60:0f:e8:00 | cut -d " " -f 1
```

then add the next line to `/etc/network/interfaces:`

```
iface <interface of your device> inet dhcp
```

This will make Gnome Network Manager ignore the interface. Then restart the networking with the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

You are going to need to disable any firewalls or configure them. I don't know how to do this, but I have seen lists of the necessary ports.

Now you can install the synce-engine, opensync libraries, and multisync front-end.

```
sudo apt-get install multisync-tools opensync-plugin-evolution opensync-plugin-synce
```

KDE users can use opensync-plugin-kdepim instead of the evolution2 plugin. There is no Thunderbird support in any stable opensync release.

Now we are going to need to setup synce and opensync. The synce-sync-engine starts up automatically if you use the ppa repository. The synce-engine should work without a config file, but you may want to download the config file and edit it (it is no longer called config.xml):

```
mkdir ~/.synce
wget -O ~/.synce/syncengine.conf.xml http://synce.svn.sf.net/svnroot/sync...fig/config.xml
gedit ~/.synce/syncengine.conf.xml
```

You may to disconnect and reconnect your device before the changes are loaded. Now you need to setup a sync profile on the device. Windows Mobile can only handle up to two profiles, so you may need to delete a profile first using synce-delete-partnership. To create a partnership use the following command. (You can tell it to sync "Contacts,Calendar,Tasks,Files". Delete the ones you don't want.)

synce-create-partnership "Linux desktop" "Contacts,Calendar,Tasks,Files"
Now we need to setup a opensync. You can use the `multisync0.90' program to setup, or you can create the group and add components via commandline:

```
msynctool --addgroup synce-sync
msynctool --addmember synce-sync synce-opensync-plugin
msynctool --addmember synce-sync evo2-sync
```

You can edit the settings with multisync0.90. To sync, press the button in multisync0.90 or do:

```
msynctool --sync synce-sync
```

You can also press the sync button within activesync on the device. By using the custom config, you can change it to popup a terminal on your computer when activesync asks for a sync instead of doing it in the background.

Comment: This seems like it's getting me somewhere, however I do get the error message about failed to get a connection. You say this indicates i've got a device password, but this is not true. i have no device password.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to get this right after about a year of multiple threads and many different ways of trying. This way took me about four hours and should take you even less with this guide.

This has been tested to work as described on a CDMA HTC Touch Pro from Sprint as well as an HTC Apache with the same radio

WARNING, BACK UP ALL CONTACTS AND EVENTS BEFORE SYNCING. IT IS HIGHLY LIKELY THAT ON YOUR FIRST SYNC YOU WILL LOSE ALL YOUR CONTACTS ON ONE OR BOTH DEVICES!
On my first sync (with all my contacts on my phone) they were wiped out and I had to manually add them all to Evolution again because I didnt have a compatible backup format and CVS sucks... PIMBackup (http://freewareppc.com/database/pimbackup.shtml) for your WM device is a nice free option

This is a guide to getting your Windows Mobile 5+ smartphone or pocket PC to sync with Evolution. It should also work (using extra opensync plug-ins) with Sunbird, KDE 3.x PIM, Blackberry, Palm, and Open Palm packages and devices. This guide, however will only focus on Windows Mobile to Evolution.

To start off, we need to install a few packages that our GUI sync apps will rely on.

sudo apt-get install synce-sync-engine synce-kpm multisync0.90
*note* There is no Gnome native sync option that I can find for Intrepid that's nearly as good as sync-kpm. I recommend it to both KDE and Gnome users. Use synce-kde or synce-gdm for Hardy

For file browsing under Nautilus in Gnome also install
sudo apt-get install synce-gnomevfs
*note* this is not necessary with newer WM 6+ devices as they give you an option to use a mass storage connection when pluged in which works like any other removable storage in Ubuntu.

Now we need to install our OpenSync plugins for use with MultiSync. For Windows Mobile and Evolution we want to run
sudo apt-get install opensync-plugin-synce opensync-plugin-evolution

At this point you want to use Alt-F2 to run synce-sync-engine then Alt-F2 and run synce-kpm

*note*synce-kpm wont create a launcher in your menu, you might want to set a desktop shortcut to it
*note* you want to make sure RNDIS is enabled on your phone by going to "Settings > Connections tab > USB to PC" and making sure the "Enable advanced network functionality" box is check, otherwise this wont work. Many other guides require this to be disabled, so if you've tried other guides to sync your WM device, this might be disabled.

At this point you should be able to connect your device and it should be recognised by the already running sync-kpm. This will ask you to create a partnership for your device.(*see issues at bottom) Pick a name and what you'd like synced and you should see a screen that shows you battery info, basic device info and an add/remove programs tab.

If at this point your device isn't detected open up ActiveSync on your device and go to "Menu > Connections" and make sure "Synchronize all PC's using this Connection:" is checked and set to USB

If that still doesn't work, try disabling the Ubuntu firewall by using (only if you are behind a router with a firewall, otherwise see bottom of post for ports to open individually)
sudo ufw disable

If you've got a connection with synce-kpm now then you can start up the program that actually makes the sync connection, MultiSync.

Start multisync by running multisync0.90 via Alt+F2 or from a terminal window. In the top left click the Add button and choose a group name for this sync profile. After choosing your group name you will be presented with a window to set up the actual sync profile.

Click the "Add Member" button and select "Evolution 2.x". Click the "Add Member" button once more and select "Plugin to synchronize with Windows CE device" and click close.

Now with the KDE PDA Manager (synce-kpm) running, click the refresh button under your newly created group in MultiSync and your contacts and calendar should sync.

Like I said, the first time it wiped my contacts from my device but it seems as long as you don't delete anything from your PC that you don't want deleted form your device then it will work fine and sync both ways. I had deleted all the contacts in Evolution to try and to a clean sync to the PC but instead it registered the deletes on my device.

- There seems to be a problem with synce-kpm registering the device as new each time it's pluged in. Each time you plug in your device to sync it you may have to create a new partnership with synce-kpm. I'm not sure how to fix this or why each new one created sticks under synce-configure-bindings but the syncing itself works so hopefully someone will be able to work out this lesser problems later.

*The individual ports to open for Windows Mobile syncing are TCP 990, 999, 5678, 5721, 26675. I'm not going into detail on how top open firewall ports, you can find this info many other places with a quick Google search.

Comment: I can't find "Enable advanced network functionality". Synce-kpm doesnt find my device even with the firewall disabled.